# Ruby dúvida apis

Tags: ruby, api, documentação

Estava lendo na documentação do ruby no [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/) sobre as classes padrões do ruby, porém eu vi que ele tem mais classes que a documentação mostra como yaml, onde posso encontrar essas apis? Quero saber quais apis existem em ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esse link são para os core methods. Para consultar os métodos extras do Ruby a própria documentação já exibe, mas em outro local. Segue o [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/).

PS: inclui a documentação YAML que você citou!

Boa sorte.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @CarlosHenrique por nada! Precisando estamos ai!